# How to replace a dataframe column-specific value with a wildcard search using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to replace dataframe column-specific value which start or ends with specific strings.

Like in below Dataframe I want to *replace* value with **blanks** if it contains specific eg.**updated** string in *words*

**Dataframe**

| Sr no# |
| --- |
| 123 |
| abcd |
| NOTUPDATED |
| notupdated |
| Notupdated |
| Updated |
| joan aulia UPDATED |
| nameUPDATED |
| not |

**Expected Output**

| Sr no# |
| --- |
| 123 |
| abcd |
|  |
|  |
|  |
| Updated |
|  |
|  |
| not |

Comment: `df.loc[df['Sr no#'].str.lower().eq('notupdated'), 'Sr no#'] = ''`

Comment: reopen question

Comment: `df.loc[df['Sr no#'].str.contains('updated', case=False), 'Sr no#'] = ''`

Comment: Use `df.loc[df['Sr no#'].str.contains(r'.+updated$', case=False), 'Sr no#'] = ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with regex with `.+` for any value before `updated`, `$` for end of strings and `case=False` for ignore cases:

```
df.loc[df['Sr no#'].str.contains(r'.+updated$', case=False), 'Sr no#'] = ''
```

Comment: @beginner_Coder - You can check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) - I can simplify it - post sample data, expected ouput and your code, what you try.